# Convert variant array values to strings in vba

Tags: arrays, string, vba, variant

I have a sub that takes a variant array generated in a userform and I would like to extract all of the values and return them as a single comma delimited string.  This is probably pretty basic, but I'm having trouble getting the values from the array into a string.  I'm getting a type mismatch when I try to cast the variant as a string.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sub formSearch(ParamArray search() As Variant)
    Dim returnString As String
    returnString = ""
    For i = LBound(search) To UBound(search)
        returnString = returnString + CStr(search(i)) + ","
    Next
    MsgBox returnString
End Sub
```

Comment: You should be able to use returnString = JOIN(array,",") on a single array!

Comment: Please show how you are calling the function.

Comment: Why is ParamArray being used here? Is it not a single array being passed in?

Comment: My guess is you are passing an array and as such `search` is an array of arrays.

Comment: try this instead of the loop: `returnString = Join(search(0), ",")`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because the input array was the contents of a NamedRange on a WorkSheet.

Even though the NamedRange was a single column of cells, the array returned by VBA was a **2-dimensional** array of values and thus the code needed the **i,1** adjustment in the CStr function to work :

```
Function getCellArrayAsString(RangeName As String) As String
    Dim arr() As Variant
    getCellArrayAsString = ""
    arr = ThisWorkbook.Names(RangeName).RefersToRange.value
    For i = LBound(arr) + 1 To UBound(arr) 
        getCellArrayAsString = getCellArrayAsString & CStr(arr(i, 1)) & ","
    Next
End Function
```

or as it would be applied to the OP's code :

```
Sub formSearch(ParamArray search() As Variant)
    Dim returnString As String
    returnString = ""
    For i = LBound(search) To UBound(search)
        returnString = returnString + CStr(search(i,1)) + ","  
    Next
    MsgBox returnString
End Sub
```

I suspect that your code suffered from the same problem in that your input was actually a 2-dimensional array.